# measuring replication lag in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-10

im trying to measure the replication time lag in my system. (postgresql 10.1)

I use a combination of `pg_last_xact_timestamp()`, `pg_last_receive_lsn()` and `pg_last_replay_lsn()` functions in a query to check the lag.

(Took an example of how to measure from [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CADKbJJWz9M0swPT3oqe8f9%2BtfD4-F54uE6Xtkh4nERpVsQnjnw%40mail.gmail.com) link)

```
postgres=# SELECT now(), pg_last_wal_receive_lsn(), pg_last_wal_replay_lsn(), EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())::INT;
               now                | pg_last_wal_receive_lsn | pg_last_wal_replay_lsn | date_part 
----------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-----------
 2018-08-06 07:00:36.540959+05:30 | 4/99B84030              | 4/99B84030             |       223
```

As it can be seen from the 2nd and 3 rd columns, the last receive lsn and replay lsn are same, meaning that the systems are in sync. But im unable to understand what is `pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()` is. How does it find out replication lag in seconds. Am i using wrong approach to measure the lag in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about `pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp`? That gives you the time when the last transaction replayed on the standby was committed on the primary.

This can be used to measure replication lag if you know that there is always some activity that is being replicated. If there is no such activity, you cannot tell replication lag from that value.

You can make sure that there is always activity by regularly calling `txid_current()`, or you can measure replication lag in bytes.

Comment: edited the question :). i thought the replication_lag was to be measured as, the diff in timestamp of the record(record insert time in primary) and now()(the time it is replayed in standby). im not following how pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() can be used for measuring lag.

Comment: I extended the answer. If there is constant activity, then the difference to the current time is a measure for replication lag.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "repmgr" package, it runs a daemon in the background and monitors this for you.

https://repmgr.org/docs/current/repmgrd-monitoring.html